# Quickly dim the iPod Touch by hitting the power button twice on the lock screen?

Tags: iphone, ipod-touch, ipod, sleep-wake, power

I've always wondered if this was a feature or not. When I'm on my iPod Touch's lock screen, then I hit the power button twice, the first hit will sleep the device, the second will wake it again but this time the screen is dim.

Is this an intentional feature? Is there anywhere I can read more about this?

This happens to me way too often because I'll often hit the power button one too many times.

Comment: Not that I know of. do you have the auto brightness option selected?  If you do, it will auto adjust the brightness of the screen when it turns on.  If your finger is near the brightness sensor near the top center of the screen it will trigger that dim look.

Comment: My iPod Touch is the latest model. It does not have an auto-brightness feature (yes, surprising, but it doesn't). So it's not that.